# C# Day from Week picker component

Tags: c#, winforms

This question is for C# 2.0 Winform.

For the moment I use checkboxes to select like this :  Monday[x], Thuesday[x]¸... etc.

It works fine but **is it a better way to get the day of the week?** (Can have more than one day picked)

Comment: is there a better way to **input** the day of the week?  -- edit suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes are the standard UI component to use when selection of multiple items is allowed. From UI usability guru [Jakob Nielsen's](http://www.useit.com/jakob/) article on 
[Checkboxes vs. Radio Buttons](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html):

> "Checkboxes are used when there are lists of options and the user may select any number of choices, including zero, one, or several. In other words, each checkbox is independent of all other checkboxes in the list, so checking one box doesn't uncheck the others."

When designing a UI, it is important to use standard or conventional components for a given task. [Using non-standard components generally causes confusion](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040913.html). For example, it would be possible to use a combo box which would allow multiple items to be selected. However, this would require the user to use Ctrl + click on the desired items, an action which is not terribly intuitive for most people.

Answer (score 2):

checkbox seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_members.aspx) with [CheckBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) on...

for a little less hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes would work fine, and there is a preexisting paradigm of that usage in Windows Scheduled Tasks.  To see that example, create a scheduled task and select Weekly for the frequency.